# Custom resolution for partially-cracked display

Tags: windows, hdmi, resolution, intel-graphics

My TV is partially cracked: the rightmost 10% doesn't display any image, making some of the UI cut off. My resolution is currently set to 4K (3840x2160). How can I make Windows think my resolution is actually 3840x1900, so it doesn't try to show anything on the right? I want to add a "margin" in software.

[image: Sceptre U650CV TV showing Windows with the right portion of the TV appearing black with a few vertical purple stripes, and the bottom-right corner having cracked glass and bezel]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ws-grid-window-manager/9nbz8nl2f408#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your display being cracked is clearly the reason the screen is partially not working

Comment: I think they mean that their screen is physically and irreversibly damaged so that there is a black area 300 px wide to the right, but the rest is still usable. They don't want to throw away the monitor just because of the dead area, and instead they want Windows to run in a user-specified resolution so that it ignores the dead area of the screen.